# Batch Word Macro to add Image Header and Footer to All Files in a Folder and Save

Tags: batch-file, macros, save, footer

I have a folder full of word documents that have no header or footer, and a template for my "letterhead" with an image for the header and text for the footer.

I need a macro that will open every file in a folder and add the header/footer to that file, then save over the old copy.

I am not sure of the best way to go about this and I haven't found a macro for it anywhere on the interwebs.

Comment: You need to post this with a word vba tag. While it could be done with batch and vbscript hybrid, It will be much easier to do in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal


for /f "Tokens=*" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d "*.doc"') do (
    Echo searching %%b
    call :AddHeaderFooter "%%b"
)
exit /b


:AddHeaderFooter <WordDoc>
setlocal
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs% echo on error resume next
>>%vbs% echo Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
>>%vbs% echo objWord.visible = false
>>%vbs% echo Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("%~1")
>>%vbs% echo With objDoc.Sections(1)
>>%vbs% echo .Headers(1).Range.inlineshapes.addpicture "C:\lh.png"
>>%vbs% echo .Footers(1).Range.Text = "Footer goes here"
>>%vbs% echo End With
>>%vbs% echo objDoc.close
>>%vbs% echo objWord.quit
>>%vbs% echo set objDoc = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo set objWord = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
exit /b
```

Modify the path to your letterhead image and what footer text you want. Put the script in the directory with your Word docs and run it from there.